# Multiple one side brackets for inner

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, arrays

Im trying to explain a code using brackets: outer brackets for the outside loop and inner brackets for the loop inside:
[image]

I understand how to write one bracket like this from the next form:

```
\[
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        Noise = (MaxValue-MinValue)*rand(1)+MinValue\\  
        k=k+1\\
    \end{array}
    \right.
\]
```

However im not sure how to make another bracket outside of this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply nest `cases` environments:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rand}{rand}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{cases}
a = 5\\
\begin{cases}
\text{Noise} = (\text{MaxValue}-\text{MinValue})*\rand(1)+\text{MinValue}\\
k=k+1
\end{cases}\\
a = a + 5
\end{cases} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]