# Right brackets for multiple code lines

Tags: brackets, pseudocode

I'm new to latex and I was wondering is there a way to achieve something like this in latex? I have searched the internet but I achieve a good solution. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371948/multiple-one-side-brackets-for-inner) post is good but it didn't have written anything on the brackets. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) As often on this website, questions like "Can I do this with LaTeX?" have yes for an answer. By searching quickly with the search option, I end up with [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51019/how-can-i-put-a-curly-brace-inside-an-algorithm-to-group-code-lines) dealing with having brackets on the right and you have [this wiki page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms) to introduce several way of typesetting algorithms with LaTeX.